# Change Charset of XML File inside function

Tags: xml, kotlin, xsd

I have a external XML file and a XSD File.
To process the files, I have to modify them.
(Charset, namespace, etc...)
At this point the problem occurs.

```
class XMLDataModifier(pathToXsd: String) {
// Pattern for XML
private val xsiPatternXML = Regex("schemaLocation=\".*\"")
private val noNamespacelocation = "noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"${pathToXsd}\""

// Pattern for XSD
private val targetNamespacePatternXSD = Regex("targetNamespace=\".*\"")

// Pattern for XML and XSD
private val encoding = Regex("encoding=\".*\"")
private val xmlnsPattern = Regex("xmlns=\".*\"")

fun modifyFile(file: XmlFile): XmlFile {
    val utf8 = Charsets.UTF_8

    val fileInputAsBytes = file.readBytes()
    var fileInput = String(fileInputAsBytes, utf8)

    println("### inside modifier - FirstCheck ###")
    println(fileInput)
    fileInput = fileInput.replace(encoding, "encoding=\"UTF-8\"")
    fileInput = fileInput.replace(xsiPatternXML, noNamespacelocation)
    fileInput = fileInput.replace(xmlnsPattern, "")

    println("### inside modifier - SecondCheck ###")
    println(fileInput)
    return XmlFile(fileInput)
}
```

If I try my function, the replacements are made.
But the print statement shows a not readable string.
I think the problem exists because of the charset is not changeing.

The Xml File (test.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<BeherbergungsVerzeichnis
        xmlns="http://xml.inek.org/schema/Standortverzeichnis"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.inek.org/schema/Standortverzeichnis"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
    <Id>11</Id>
    <Vorname>Günther</Vorname>
    <Nachname>Hartmannsgruber</Nachname>
</Beherbergungsverzeichnis>
```

Output after running the function

```
### inside modifier FirstCheck ###
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<BeherbergungsVerzeichnis
        xmlns="http://xml.inek.org/schema/Standortverzeichnis"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.inek.org/schema/Standortverzeichnis"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
    <Id>11</Id>
    <Vorname>G�nther</Vorname>
    <Nachname>Hartmannsgruber</Nachname>
</Beherbergungsverzeichnis>

### inside modifier SecondCheck ###
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BeherbergungsVerzeichnis
        
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/home/user/IdeaProjects/StandortKonverterGradle/src/main/resources/data/testxsd.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
    <Id>11</Id>
    <Vorname>G�nther</Vorname>
    <Nachname>Hartmannsgruber</Nachname>
</Beherbergungsverzeichnis>
Fehler beim Validieren der XML-Datei: /home/benhartmannsgruber/IdeaProjects/StandortKonverterGradle/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Why appears the wrong char for "ü" although the charset are set to UTF-8?
Is there a better solution for reading and processing a File which don't need to be saved?

Thanks for help!

Comment: The xml file is not written by me. It comes form an website. Modification is needed because parsing is not possible.
The file contains an scheme URL wich does not exists. But the scheme can be downloaded seperately and parsed localy.

Comment: Where is that `XmlFile` class from? Is there a public API documentation online?

Answer (score 0):

There's something badly wrong with your application architecture if you need to modify XML files at the lexical level before parsing them. Generally you should only read and write XML files using XML-based tools such as XSLT and XQuery.

Trying to change the value of the "encoding" attribute in the XML declaration is going to give you a failure unless you also change the actual encoding of the contents of the file correspondingly. It looks like you have set it to a value which doesn't match the actual file encoding.

Comment: The xml file is not written by me. It comes form an website. Modification is needed because parsing is not possible.

Comment: If it's not well-formed XML then it would be better not to refer to it in your question as an XML file. If you need to repair broken XML then you need to explain very clearly and carefully what the nature of the brokenness is. However, the best solution is always to get the XML fixed at source.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how parsing of an XML document (without validation) should fail just because there is a wrong schemaLocation; therefore I think you can fix the XML with XML tools like XSLT 3, the following stylesheet allows you to set the local file URI to the schema file as a global parameter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:param name="schema-uri" as="xs:string">file:///C:/Home/username/schema.xsd</xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*/@xsi:schemaLocation">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" select="namespace-uri(/*),$schema-uri"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><BeherbergungsVerzeichnis xmlns="http://xml.inek.org/schema/Standortverzeichnis" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.inek.org/schema/Standortverzeichnis file:///C:/Home/username/schema.xsd">
    <Id>11</Id>
    <Vorname>Günther</Vorname>
    <Nachname>Hartmannsgruber</Nachname>
</BeherbergungsVerzeichnis>
```

XSLT 3 can be run with Java/Kotlin using Saxon 9.8 HE or later (currently supported versions are HE 11.6 and 12.3).

But is also possible to solve this task with XSLT 1.0 which any Java JRE supports with the JAXP Transformer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:param name="schema-uri">file:///C:/Home/username/schema.xsd</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*/@xsi:schemaLocation">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(namespace-uri(/*),' ', $schema-uri)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```